# Add n elements numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to add *n* elements with the same value until the length of the array reaches 100.

For example

```
my_array = numpy.array([3, 4, 5])
```

Note that I do not know the length of the array beforehand. It may be anything 3 <= x <= 100

I want to add (100 - x) more elements, all with the value 9. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean, you "cannot" have length of the array known?

Comment: Yes, the array is generated by another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to remember with numpy arrays, you can't add elements like you can with lists.  So adding numbers to an array is not really the best thing to do.

Far better is to *start* with an array, and replace the elements with new data as it comes in.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
MY_SPECIAL_NUMBER = 100
my_array = np.array[3, 4, 5]
my_new_array = np.ones(100) * MY_SPECIAL_NUMBER
my_new_array[:my_array.size] = my_array
```

`my_new_array` is now what you want.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to approach this: concatenating arrays or assigning them.

You can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) and generate an appropriately sized array:

```
my_array = # as you defined it
remainder = [9] * (100 - len(my_array))
remainder = np.array(remainder)
a100 = np.concatenate((my_array, remainder))
```

Alternatively, you can construct a [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full) array, and then overwrite some of the values using slice notation:

```
a100 = numpy.full(100, 9)
my_array = # as you defined it
a100[0:len(my_array)] = my_array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you "cannot" know the size of your mysterious array:

```
fillvalue=9
padding=numpy.ones(100)*fillvalue
newarray=numpy.append(myarray, padding)
newarray=newarray[:100]
```